# Is it possible to add a "Combine" step to the Amazon Elastic MapReduce workflow?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, combiners

I am referring to the Combine step [mentioned on the Hadoop wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce).  I have been unable to find a reference to it in the AWS documentation, and I'd like to utilize this step.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for Combiner will be in the Apache documentation and not in the AWS documentation. Amazon Elastic MapReduce supports [0.18.3 and 0.20.2](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/faqs/#dev-12) versions of Hadoop with custom patches. Apache [MR Tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html) has reference to how the combiner function should be used. Call the [Job.setCombinerClass()](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setCombinerClass%28java.lang.Class%29) to set the combiner class.